# linq2sql, use different databases with one .dbml

Tags: c#, linq

I am working with a few different databases (3 MS SQL, 2 SYBASE v12.5). They all have the same structure/schema.

I have used the Designer to make an initial .dbml (extends from data.linq.DataContext with C# 4.0). DataContext has a constructor that takes one argument (a connection string). Considering all databases look alike in structure, I use this to switch the database from which I query (works great with MS SQL).

1. Will I be able to substitute a connection string for my SYBASE databases ?
2. Before getting to that, I keep getting errors on the connection string I am trying to build at the moment.
   I am trying the following provided on connectionStrings.com with no success :
   Provider=Sybase.ASEOLEDBProvider.2;Server Name=myASEserver;Server Port Address=5000;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
   I get an error saying the keyword "provider" is not recognized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

linq2sql only supports Ms SQL Server. There is no provider attribute in the connection string for the underlying Sqlclient.